# Apex 4.0.2 Primary Key Incrementation from with-in an Application

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, sqlplus

So as apart of of a project I am doing I have been restricted on the editing of the Database from which I am building this application. I can not directly make changes to the Database from the SQL Command Prompt, all changes and new entries have to be made through Apex. Just clarifying this.

So I have a table TAXIUSER that has a primary key of TAXIUSERID. The primary key format for data currently in the Database is as follows:

- UID0001
- UID0002

and so on. Currently the user has to manually enter a new primary key each time they add an entry to the table. How through the Apex application solely (I can't use SQL Workshop either!) can I achieve something that would allow the user to not have to manually enter the primary key and preferably have it increment still in the above format.

EDIT: Sorry I should clarify I am using an Form on a Table with Report and version 11g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a read only item with a default value (or a computation) of

```
SELECT
  'UID'||LPAD(MAX(SUBSTR(taxiuserid,4) + 1),4,0)
  FROM 
  taxiuser;
```

Note that your prerequisites (no access to db) are forcing this to be a flawed approach:

- Errors out with primary key constraint violation if 2 or more users are creating records at the same time. You could minimize the risk by calculating the new value on submit but then the user will not see the value when they're creating the user
- Only works for the first 9999 users

Edit: If you use the computation after submit method, you will need to add condition to allow edits to made to existing entries. Otherwise the computation will attempt to change the primary key of that entry causing an error. To do this simply add a condition of Value in Expression 1 is Null, then specify the column from which the data is being entered into the table, like as follows:

```
P8_TAXIUSERID
```

This essentially means the computation will only ever attempt a value to TAXIUSERID when P8_TAXIUSERID (the column from which your are entering the data) contains a null value.

Comment: Thanks, will be sure to try that later when I get a moment. Sadly those are the constraints (pun intended) I have been given. So essentially it's the best I can do with with Apex

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, I have been working on it and while this works as in. In a protected text field it shows the correct user ID but when i try to create an entry, it gives me an error that null cannot be inserted. cannot insert NULL into ("STUDENT"."TAXIUSER"."TAXIUSERID")

Comment: Don't worry I have now implement this as suggested above by calculating on submit. Which works perfect fine, thank you.

Comment: I have run into an issue. Now if I try to make changes to an entry it will attempt to change the ID number. Which results in an error, how can I get around this?

Comment: Update: I fixed this by adding a condition Item is Null. Will make an edit to you post to include.